# What is the purpose of the "Handy time stamps" in the time package?

Tags: go

Reference:

I am trying to figure out what the "Handy Time Stamp" are used for in the time package.

I can parse dates just fine using the other constants such as RFC

```
t, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC822, "02 Jan 06 15:04 MST")
fmt.Println(t.Unix())
```

> ```
> Output 1136214240
> ```

vs

```
t, _ := time.Parse(time.Stamp, "Jan _2 15:04:05")
fmt.Println(t.Unix())
```

> ```
> Output: -62135596800
> ```

The last output is wrong. What am I missing here? How are these timestamps useful?

Below is the Godoc for time constants:

```
const (
        ANSIC       = "Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 2006"
        UnixDate    = "Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 MST 2006"
        RubyDate    = "Mon Jan 02 15:04:05 -0700 2006"
        RFC822      = "02 Jan 06 15:04 MST"
        RFC822Z     = "02 Jan 06 15:04 -0700" // RFC822 with numeric zone
        RFC850      = "Monday, 02-Jan-06 15:04:05 MST"
        RFC1123     = "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 MST"
        RFC1123Z    = "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700" // RFC1123 with numeric zone
        RFC3339     = "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"
        RFC3339Nano = "2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999Z07:00"
        Kitchen     = "3:04PM"
        // Handy time stamps.
        Stamp      = "Jan _2 15:04:05"
        StampMilli = "Jan _2 15:04:05.000"
        StampMicro = "Jan _2 15:04:05.000000"
        StampNano  = "Jan _2 15:04:05.000000000"
)
```

Comment: Those two dates are different; the one you pass to `RFC822` is in 2006 and on MST. The `Stamp` one doesn't have year or time zone specified, so it probably picks this year and your time zone.

Comment: @nmichaels if it was for this year and my timezone, then wouldn't the output be a positive number?

Comment: If I knew the answer to the question, I would have answered it. I don't know why it's negative, but whatever else is wrong with it, those dates aren't the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The last output is wrong. What am I missing here? How are these timestamps useful?

You are definitely missing an error check here, let's add it

```
t, err := time.Parse(time.Stamp, "Jan _2 15:04:05")
fmt.Println(err)
fmt.Println(t.Unix())
```

Output:

> parsing time "Jan _2 15:04:05" as "Jan _2 15:04:05": cannot parse "_2
>   15:04:05" as "_2"
>   -62135596800

The correct string would be "Jan  2 15:04:05" (note the double space between Jan and 2). About underscore from the docs:

> Within the format string, an underscore _ represents a space that may
>   be replaced by a digit if the following number (a day) has two digits;
>   for compatibility with fixed-width Unix time formats.

Then, why it's representations as UNIX time is negative, let's check:

```
t, err := time.Parse(time.Stamp, "Jan  2 15:04:05")
fmt.Println(err)
fmt.Println(t)
```

Output:

```
<nil>
0000-01-02 15:04:05 +0000 UTC
```

So it's negative because the year is 0000.

And finally, where it can be useful? For example, to measure duration of time-consuming operations. You can output to logs current time in one of Stamp formats along with some messages like "Started doing this", "Finished doing that". Then, because it's fixed-width format and without unnecessary year information - it's easy to read the logs, easy to parse such logs.

This format is actually used in "syslog" in *nix.

Comment: Here is a playground example for illustration: http://play.golang.org/p/VGZxl1G8R_